# How to know if panel i showing

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

So. I'm having some issues where my panel is not always displaying (though it seems the rest of the add-on is still working). I'm trying to write some logs to find out why this is happening, but there are some things I don't really understand.

To experiment I made a simple add-on as such

```
// main.js
const panels        = require("panel");
const {Cc, Ci}      = require("chrome");
const widgets       = require("widget");

var my_widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "google-link",
    label: "Click me",
    contentURL: "http://google.com/favicon.ico",
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    panel: my_panel,
    onClick: function() {
        my_panel.show();
        console.log('Panel displaying? ' + my_panel.isShowing);
    }
});

var my_panel = panels.Panel({
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    contentURL: "http://google.com",
});

my_panel.port.on("show", function() {
    console.log('Panel emitted show');
});
```

What happens is firstly: the `isShowing` is always `false`, even when I clearly see the panel. And the `show` event never seems to get triggered (I'm really looking to catch the `error` event, but this is just to find events in the first place).

The fine print: This is using SDK 1.6.1 and Firefox 10ESR. Perhaps this is something that is solved in later versions, I don't know. Either way I'd like to know if I'm thinking right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not quite right, see this variation:

```
// main.js
const panels        = require("panel");
const {Cc, Ci}      = require("chrome");
const widgets       = require("widget");

var my_widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "google-link",
    label: "Click me",
    contentURL: "http://google.com/favicon.ico",
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    panel: my_panel,
    onClick: function() {
        my_panel.show();
        // this is false because the panel is shown asynchronously
        console.log('Panel displaying? ' + my_panel.isShowing);
    }
});

var my_panel = panels.Panel({
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    contentURL: "http://google.com",
});

// there is no port property on panel
my_panel.on("show", function() {
    console.log('Panel emitted show');
    // this is true...
    console.log('Panel displaying? ' + my_panel.isShowing);
});
```

The code is here:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/161691/latest/

Comment: Aha! That does it now. +1 for the info that `show()` is async.